# Properties of universal fibration

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

I am trying to read the following paper [1] (Becker, James C.; Gottlieb, Daniel Henry
Coverings of fibrations.
Compositio Math.26(1973)) where the authors mentioned that for any fiber $F$,
there exists a universal fibration $F \to E_{\infty} \to B_{\infty}$. They referred to the following book [2](Dold, Albrecht
Halbexakte Homotopiefunktoren.
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 12
Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1966.) which is very hard for me to find.

From a Google search, I found the following link [3], which I find very difficult to understand as I am not very conversant with this topic.

I wish to understand the construction and properties of the spaces $E_{\infty}$, $B_{\infty}$.

I will be really grateful if I can get an accessible reference for such spaces or some link where this book is accessible.

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0322867

[2] https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0198464

[3]https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+fibration+of+%28infinity%2C1%29-categories

Comment: The mathscinet links require sign in. Could you instead include the title/authors of the article/book?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I have added the name of the article and the book.

Comment: If the fiber if a connected CW complex, a very explicit discription of the universal fibration can be found in the paper "The total space of universal fibration" by Gottlieb, 1973, see  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-46/issue-2/The-total-space-of-universal-fibrations/pjm/1102946316.pdf.